# Domain Ownership Criteria (.eu)

Tags: domain, dns-hosting, domain-registration

< Reposted from Stack Overflow on recommendation >

Depending on the outcome of discussions political in the UK, we may lose the right to hold .eu domains on the 29th of the month. This is mandated by EurID who hold authority over the .eu domain.

https://eurid.eu/en/register-a-eu-domain/brexit-notice/

The only viable ways to work around this are to transfer the ownership of the domain to a European registered location, or lose the domain. EurID have already stated they plan to offer a very limited period of flexibility, but after the 29th of March they will be looking to lock down any changes to the domains from UK locations.

My question is what constitutes a change in domain ownership? I have a friend in Germany who is quite happy to hold the domain for me for a year or so to offer a migration period. I have been told by Ionos that changing the Reg-C contact details is all I need do to transfer the domain. This seems a bit simplistic to me, does this really constitute a full transfer?

Cheers

Rob

Comment: I'd contact your registrar's support to get a solid answer to this.

Comment: Good advice ceejayoz, see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply changing your domain's contact details doesn't constitute a transfer of the domain, but it seems to be sufficient in this case.

In the case of the no-deal Brexit:

> On 30 March 2019, as of 00:00:00 CET, EURid will again notify by email both GB/GI registrants and their registrars that their domain name(s) is not in compliance with the .eu regulatory framework. Registrants will be given the possibility to demonstrate their compliance with the .eu regulatory framework by updating their contact data (e.g. indicating a legally established entity in one of the eligible EU27 or EEA Member States, or update of residence) before 30 May 2019, 00:00:00 CEST. During this two-month period, the domain names in question will remain active.

Comment: Michael, I followed up with EurID as ceejayoz suggested. I was hesitant asking the gamekeeper to advise the moocher... However, it made sense. You are correct. They have confirmed that the actual account the domain is held in with my ISP doesn't matter to them, they don't have visibility of it. They are only concerned that the registered address of the "responsible adult" is within the EU legal jurisdiction. So changing the contact details in the WHOIS is sufficient for them. They have their named responsible person, and they are within the EU.   Thanks for your help.